# How to share Apache2 virtual host configuration between two linux servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, virtualhost

What is the best option to share configuration directives between Apache2 servers. This is required in order to employ stable load balancing. The most important directives are those that define the virtual hosts.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Google "configuration management" and consider one of the tools, particularly Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

We define one host as the "master", also (as per most distributions these days) the virtual host configuration is kept in a folder /etc/apache2/vhost.d/ and allocated a file per virtualhost.

e.g.

```
www.example.com.conf
customers.example.com.conf
suppliers.example.com.conf
... and so on..
```

Then a cron'd rsync that copies from the "master" to the other servers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to solve this:

1. put the config on centralized storage, for example NFS or CIFS.
2. use a versioning system (git, svn, etc) to store the configurations and check them out on the webservers
3. sync configuration from one server to the other using rsync or scp

You could consider combining the 2nd option with some provisioning tool like Puppet or CFengine so that Apache will be reloaded when the central configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a unified configuration for our development, staging, and production servers.  Most of the configuration is the same for all of them.  Where they're different, I put the differences either into virtual host definitions, or in `<IfDefine>` sections, for example:

```
<IfDefine DEVELOPMENT>
...
</IfDefine>
```

Each server starts with a command-line switch that tells which server it is.  For example, on the development server I put

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS="-DDEVELOPMENT"
```

into /etc/apache2/envvars (that's for Debian - for RedHat you'd put `OPTIONS='-DDEVELOPMENT'` into /etc/sysconfig/httpd).  So besides its virtual hosts, the development server has all of the configuration within the `<IfDefine DEVELOPMENT>` sections.

When the configuration changes, I commit the changes to version control, usually in development, and push them to the other hosts.